# Why is pyperclip not copying result of phone numbers to clipboard

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner learning python with Automate The Boring Stuff by Al Sweigart.

I'm currently on the part where he created a program using Regular expression on how to extract emails and phone numbers from documents and have them pasted to another document.

Below is the script:

```
#! python3

import re
import pyperclip 

# Create a regex for phone numbers 
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''
# 08108989212

(\d{11})    # Full phone number


''', re.VERBOSE)

#Create a regex for email a`enter code here`ddressess 
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''
# some.+_thing@(\d{2,5}))?.com 

[a-zA-Z0-9_.+] +    # name part 
@                   # @symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+] +    # domain name part

''', re.VERBOSE)

#Get the text off the clipboard 
text = pyperclip.paste()

# TODO: Extract the email/phone from this text 
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)

allPhoneNumbers = []
for allPhoneNumber in extractedPhone:
    allPhoneNumbers.append(allPhoneNumber[0])

print(extractedPhone)
print(extractedEmail)

# Copy the extracted email/phone to the clipboard
results = '\n'.join(allPhoneNumbers) + '\n' + '\n'.join(extractedEmail)
pyperclip.copy(results)
```

The script is expected to extract, print both phone numbers and email addresses to the terminal which it does. It is also expected to copy the extracted phone number and email addresses to the clipboard automatically, so they can be pasted to another text editor or word document.

Now the problem is, it copies only the email address but converts the phone numbers to 0 when pasted.

What am i not getting right?

Please pardon the errors in my English.

Answer (score 0):

for library: phonenumbers ([pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers), [source](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers))

> Python version of Google's common library for parsing, formatting,
>   storing and validating international phone numbers.

I think you will need to use this to format those phone numbers.

To be more specific, you'll need to install the package using:

```
pip install phonenumbers
```

The main object that the library deals with is a PhoneNumber object. You can create this from a string representing a phone number using the parse function, but you also need to specify the country that the phone number is being dialled from (unless the number is in E.164 format, which is globally unique).

```
import phonenumbers
    x = phonenumbers.parse("+442083661177", None)
    print(x)
Country Code: 44 National Number: 2083661177 Leading Zero: False
    type(x)
    <class 'phonenumbers.phonenumber.PhoneNumber'>
    y = phonenumbers.parse("020 8366 1177", "GB")
    print(y)
Country Code: 44 National Number: 2083661177 Leading Zero: False
    x == y
    True
z = phonenumbers.parse("00 1 650 253 2222", "GB")  # as dialled from GB, not a GB number
    print(z)
Country Code: 1 National Number: 6502532222 Leading Zero(s): False
```

More information can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/

Comment: I don't really understand, but can i get a link to that, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't need this part of your code

```
allPhoneNumbers = []
for allPhoneNumber in extractedPhone:
    allPhoneNumbers.append(allPhoneNumber[0])
```

all it does is to create list with first char (obviously always `0`) from all extracted phone numbers.
Then change the result as follows:

```
results = '\n'.join(extractedPhone) + '\n' + '\n'.join(extractedEmail)
```